# How to set media player to alarm usage in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

Can someone please show me how to set my media player to play with alarm volume. I want to set the media player to alarm usage. I've tried what others have said and no success. Can I get a modern example in kotlin please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaPlayer` has a method called `setAudioAttributes`. The `AudioAttributes` passed to this method control the audio stream that audio file will be played in.

In order to make the `MediaPlayer` play in the alarm stream, You have to set the `usage` of the `AudioAttributes` to `USAGE_ALARM`. There is a dedicated `Builder` class for creating `AudioAttributes` which is used in the code below. Besides that You also want to specify the `contentType` attribute - for the alarms the most suitable will most likely be `CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC`. Here is the example, modern kotlin code:

```kotlin
mediaPlayer.apply {
    reset()
    setAudioAttributes( // Here is the important part
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM) // usage - alarm
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build()
    )
    setDataSource(
        context,
        alarmSoundUri
    )
    isLooping = true
    prepare()
    start()
}
```

Comment: Ty, I will try this later and see if I can get it to work.